# tabularx fill on certain column

Tags: tabularx

I have a reaccuring table which I want to be the same. Currently the width would be different depending how wide the text is in the "Titel" column. How should I do it so it looks the same every time I use the table?

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{||c c c c||} 
    \hline
    ID & Titel & Schätzung & Effektiv \\ [0.5ex] 
    \hline\hline
    101 & Übernahme Frontend Design von Prototyp & 2 & 2 \\ 
    \hline
    102 & Draftable Demo zu Spring Boot & 2 & 8 \\
    \hline
    103 & PDF Diff Demo zu Spring Boot & 1 & 4 \\
    \hline
   \end{tabularx}
```

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please add a fully compilable MWE?

Comment: never use tabularx with a specification like `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{||c c c c||} `  you have to have at least one X column, just use `tabular` and fixed width `p{...}` columns.

Comment: If the entries in the first, third and fourth column always have the same width in all tables, you could also use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{||c X c c||} `

Comment: Please see my added answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you did not explain what you mean with:

> How should I do it so it looks the same every time I use the table?

Therefore I will show you some possibilities you can use:

1. `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{||c X c c||}` creates an table always spread over the length of the text `\textwidth` with an variable column marked with `X` and three columns with centered content marked with `c`. Depending on the length of the title or the datas for the three columns marked with `c` it could be usefull to use  `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{||X X X X||}` instead ...
2. If you need not the varaible column `X` from `tabularx` you can use the following `\begin{tabular}{||c p{6.9cm} c c||}` with an fixed second column to 6.9 cm length. With the current datas your table fits then the given typing area marked with package `showframe` in the resulting pdf. You will have to change the value `6.9cm` to another value if you have longer or perhaps shorter titles for the first, third and forth column ...
3. If you want to have fixed lengthes for all columns you can for example use `\begin{tabular}{||p{1cm} p{6.7cm} p{1.5cm} p{1cm}||}` for the given table datas ...
4. At last I show you the third table without any vertical lines and only two horizontal lines with `\begin{tabular}{p{1cm} p{6.7cm} p{1.5cm} p{1cm}}` and please see the deleted `\hline` commands in forth table. It looks mutch better than version three, what do you think? Of course you can delete the horizontal and vertical lines in the tables before in the same way ...

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe} % <============ visualize typing area and margins


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{||c X c c||} 
\hline
ID  & Titel                                  & Schätzung & Effektiv \\[0.5ex] 
\hline\hline
101 & Übernahme Frontend Design von Prototyp & 2         & 2 \\ 
\hline
102 & Draftable Demo zu Spring Boot          & 2         & 8 \\
\hline
103 & PDF Diff Demo zu Spring Boot           & 1         & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

Second version:

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{||c p{6.9cm} c c||} 
\hline
ID  & Titel                                  & Schätzung & Effektiv \\[0.5ex] 
\hline\hline
101 & Übernahme Frontend Design von Prototyp & 2         & 2 \\ 
\hline
102 & Draftable Demo zu Spring Boot          & 2         & 8 \\
\hline
103 & PDF Diff Demo zu Spring Boot           & 1         & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

Third version:

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{||p{1cm} p{6.7cm} p{1.5cm} p{1cm}||} 
\hline
ID  & Titel                                  & Schätzung & Effektiv \\[0.5ex] 
\hline\hline
101 & Übernahme Frontend Design von Prototyp & 2         & 2 \\ 
\hline
102 & Draftable Demo zu Spring Boot          & 2         & 8 \\
\hline
103 & PDF Diff Demo zu Spring Boot           & 1         & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

Fourth version (simply deleted nearly all commands \texttt{\textbackslash hline} and all vertical lines):

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{p{1cm} p{6.7cm} p{1.5cm} p{1cm}} 
ID  & Titel                                  & Schätzung & Effektiv \\[0.5ex] 
\hline
101 & Übernahme Frontend Design von Prototyp & 2         & 2 \\ 
102 & Draftable Demo zu Spring Boot          & 2         & 8 \\
103 & PDF Diff Demo zu Spring Boot           & 1         & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting tables]

Depending on your used documentclass your result can be different, play with the used length then. Also there is the question how the numbers should be displayed: centered, right, left or aligned at the decimal point? But that can be discussed in an follow-up-question, if needed ...